# Adding a custom error message in VeeValidate3 and VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vee-validate, vuejs3

I'm trying to add a new error message for a custom validator.
First, i changed the default language for validation errors this way:

```
import VeeValidate, { Validator } from 'vee-validate';
import it from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/it';


Validator.localize({ it: it });
Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false, fastExit: false, locale: 'it' });
```

Here's the extended validator (in another file):

```
this.$validator.extend('dateFormat', {
                    validate: value => {
                        let reg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]/;
                    
                    if (reg.exec(value) === null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            validators.push('dateFormat');
```

How can i show a custom message when the date format is not correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, do not know if it is the best practice but seems to work:

```
//Add this line
it.messages.dateFormat = function (field) { return 'Format for ' + field + ' not valid'; };
Validator.localize({ it: it });
Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false, fastExit: false, locale: 'it' });
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out! If I had to guess, I'd wager that the thing stopping the other solution from working is something to do with localization... The docs provide another way of adding messages for locales [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-the-default-i18n) that may be worth taking a look at.

Comment: Actually, I think that's exactly what's going on here, `it.messages.dateFormat` is doing the same thing as [the docs show](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-the-default-i18n), just shorthand. I'll add that syntax from the docs to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Two ways:** (Per the [VeeValidate3 docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#messages))

You can change the error message by returning strings in the validation function itself:

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';

extend('positive', value => {
    if (value >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return 'This field must be a positive number';
});
```

*Or*, you can use the extended format and pass in a `message` property:

```js
this.$validator.extend('dateFormat', {
    validate: value => {
        let reg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]/;
               
        if (reg.exec(value) === null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
    // message property:
    message: 'The date format is incorrect',
});
validators.push('dateFormat');
```

---

**Localization**

The aforementioned solutions fall short if you're looking to support multiple languages.

Based on [the docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-the-default-i18n), you should be able to add localized messages for any language using the `{ localize }` import and the following object syntax:

```js
import { localize } from 'vee-validate';

localize({
  en: {
    messages: {
      required: 'this field is required',
      min: 'this field must have no less than {length} characters',
      max: (_, { length }) => `this field must have no more than ${length} characters`
    }
  }
});
```

---

As a sidenote, you can also simplify your `if (reg.exec(value) === null) ...` lines to:

```js
return reg.exec(value) !== null;
```

Comment: I tried to pass the 'message' property but it seems to still return the _default message, that is, 'The {_field_} value is not valid'
Is it something related to the HTML element?